# How to scroll the document with div resize (jquery ui)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-resizable

I'm using jquery resizable plugin with custom handle. I want to scroll site down when handle reaches the bottom of the window- ideally the way draggable plugin works, when dragging divs outside visible area of the document. I'm resizing only along y axis, using "s" handle.

**UPDATE:** jsfiddle avaible here: http://jsfiddle.net/yazgY/10/

So far resizing works fine:

```
$(function() {
    $("#mask_container").resizable({handles: {'s': '#button'}});
});
```

Basic structure of html looks like this:

```
<div id="mask_container" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div id="mask"></div>
    <div id="button" class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>
</div>
```

I was trying to implement parts of the code from draggable that is responsible for scrolling, but with no luck so far :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `scrollTop` method to achieve that effect after the resize event has stopped. Try this:

**JS**

```
$("#mask_container").resizable({
    handles: {
        's': '#button'
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
        var masContainerHeight = ui.size.height;

        if (masContainerHeight > viewportHeight) {
            $("html, body").animate({
               scrollTop: $(document).height() - $(window).height()
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yazgY/11/